# Dovecot not respecting conf.d settings

Tags: mail-server, dovecot

I am trying to setup Dovecot according to [a guide](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/4/). I am trying to disable POP3 and change the certificate locations, however changing 01-mail-stack-delivery.conf does not seem to make a difference. Changing 10-ssl.conf and 20-pop3.conf individually does not change anything either. Do I have to enable the conf.d folder somewhere? I am using `service dovecot restart` to restart dovecot and `dovecot -n` to view the current settings.

Comment: Do you have `!include conf.d/*.conf` in your `dovecot.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the dovecot mailing list, I had a config file that was loaded after that was overriding settings to the default